# i get 'else' without 'if' error

Tags: java

I get 'else' without 'if' error.
Please help, thank you

```
class MyGraphics
{
    FrameBuffer fb;
    int x, y;
    private int width, height;
    MyGraphics(int wid, int hit)
    {
        fb= new FrameBuffer(wid,hit);
        width = fb.getWidth();
        height = fb.getHeight();
    }
    MyGraphics()
    {
        fb = new FrameBuffer();
        width = fb.getWidth();
        height = fb.getHeight();
    }


    void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    int x0;
    double y0 = y1;
    double slope = (double)(y2 - y1) / (double)(x2 - x1);

    if (x2 < width && y2 < height)
    {
        for (x0 = x1; x0<=x2; x0++)

        y0=y0+ slope;
    }

    fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));

    else if(x2 < width && y2 >= height)
    {
        for( y0=y1,x0=x1;  (int)y0< height;   x0++)
            y0 = y0 + slope;
    }
    fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));

    else if(x2 >= width && y2 <height)
    {
        for (x0 = x1; x0 < width; x0++)
        y0=y0+ slope;
    }
    fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));

    else
    {
        for(x0=x1; x0 < width && (int)y0 < height;x0++)
            y0 = y0 + slope;
        fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));
    }

    return;
}
void display()
{
    fb.display();
    return;
}

}
```

Comment: If you'd indent your code clearly and correctly, it would be quite obvious. You are missing a }.

Comment: Please indent your code properly and you will know the problem.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? We can't be ***all*** wrong...

Comment: Install an IDE and you won't have problems like this. I personally like Eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/

Comment: I Agree with Jordan. Try using any one of the IDE's used by java developers like  Eclipse/ Intellij [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) / Netbeans [link](http://netbeans.org/). You could have resolved all the errors by yourself with help of IDE.

Answer (score 2):

This is how your code looks after proper indentation:

```
if (x2 < width && y2 < height)
{
  for (x0 = x1; x0<=x2; x0++)
      y0=y0+ slope;
}
fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));

/* THIS ELSE HAS NO MATCHING IF */
else if(x2 < width && y2 >= height)
{
    for( y0=y1,x0=x1;  (int)y0< height;   x0++)
        y0 = y0 + slope;
}
fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));

/* NEITHER DOES THIS ONE */
else if(x2 >= width && y2 <height)
{
    for (x0 = x1; x0 < width; x0++)
    y0=y0+ slope;
}
fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));

/* NOR THIS ONE */
else
{
    for(x0=x1; x0 < width && (int)y0 < height;x0++)
        y0 = y0 + slope;
    fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));
}
```

Comment: Does some downvoter believe those `else`s do have a matching `if`...?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing bracket after the initial if...

But your compiler should have told you exactly where to look.

You have multiple bracket issues...if you are using an IDE try having it format your code, or at least highlight matching brackets.  This should help narrow the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if (x2 < width && y2 < height)
{
  // if body
}
fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0)); 
else if(x2 < width && y2 >= height) // this else has no matching if.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you specified (`else` without `if`) is exactly correct. Look at your code:

```
if (x2 < width && y2 < height) {   
  for (x0 = x1; x0<=x2; x0++)

    y0=y0+ slope;
    }

    fb.setPixel(x0, ((int)y0));

else if(x2 < width && y2 >= height)
```

Here, you've ended your `if` statement after `y0 = y0 + slope`, and do `fb.setPixel` afterwards. When you get to the `else if`, there's no matching `if`, because you've already ended it and performed statements after it.

Answer (score 1):

Problems are solved by others.

Here's my 2 advices:

1. use "tab" to make your code in a better look.
2. when it comes to brackets issue, always type "{" and "}" first, then add things between them. Then you'll never get this kind of errors again.

These are my ways, you may use them if useful.

What's more, you could use an IDE. Things would get much better. Most IDE's default setting is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check values for width/ height and also did your code compile? You are missing a `}` after if